# Selenium IDE - Placeholder

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ide, placeholder

Estou com dificuldades em automatizar um teste onde preencho um campo (placeholder) e salvo. Ao consultar o que salvei, verifico que a informação inserida no campo não foi feita.

```
<input id="nomeCliente" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" _ngcontent-c8="" maxlength="150" placeholder="Nome Cliente" type="text" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

Comment: Preenche o campo e quer testar o valor? Não entendi o placeholder.

Comment: @Aline Isso mesmo. Eu quero preencher o campo com valor. O campo é preenchido. No entanto, ao consultar depois, o campo não está com o valor.
Há algum outro comando sem ser o "Type"?

Comment: Adiciona seu código com selenium pra vermos.

Comment: @Aline Consegui com o comando "sendKeys".
No entanto, agora não consigo mais substituir uma palavra por outra no campo. Ela apenas vai sendo inserida na frente do já inserido.
Segue o comando (este não é placeholder, mas acontece a mesma coisa):

<tr>
 <td>sendKeys</td>
 <td>xpath=(//input[@type='text'])[10]</td>
 <td>testeteste</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>sendKeys</td>
 <td>xpath=(//input[@type='text'])[10]</td>
 <td>teste</td>
</tr>

No aguardo!
Muito obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholder não tem nada a ver com o tipo do campo, o que você precisa trabalhar é com o input, placeholder é apenas uma propriedade de um input, sugiro que leia mais sobre isto no seguinte [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

A respeito do seu real problema, é a forma com que está tentando enviar informações para o campo. Sempre que precisar inserir dados em um campo de texto(input) você deve usar o método sendKeys(), caso necessite limpar os dados antes de inserir(para que não seja concatenado valores) basta utilizar o comando clear().

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("nomeCliente")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("nomeCliente")).sendKeys("Nome Cliente");
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode estar pegando o campo errado para facilitar , você pode pegar este campo da forma a baixo:

`driver.findElement(By.id("nomeCliente")).sendKeys("Nome Cliente");`

desta forma você vai encontrar o elemento via ID e passar o que quer preencher com o sendKeys